# select option with default value undefined with required attribute does not work but value empty

Tags: angular, angular2-form-validation

I have a dropdown of countries

```
<select  #countryInput  name="country" [(ngModel)]="room.countryId"   required>
  <option   [selected] [value]="undefined">Select Country</option>
  <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c.id">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In order to "Select Country" option, it is required to set [value]="undefined" otherwise it would not be shown as default selection instead empty selection.

Even though field marked is as required, on form submit required wont be show as it does for

```
<option value="">Select Country</option>
```

which is default behaviour in html 5:

[image]

As a work around handle validation on form submit, but this time first required fields will be validated but lastly country field.

```
if (this.room.country == undefined) {
   alert('select country ');
   return false;
}
```

What could be solution to field with [value]="undefined" and show "Please select an item first" alert?

See the [forked fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-hbcwgo) from Daniel's

Comment: I don’t get what you mean with the part why it would be required to set the value to `undefined`?

Comment: It means, if you want to show as default option in select element, options has to have value "undefined"

Comment: Are you talking about any specific requirements introduced by angular? Because in HTML itself, there is no such requirement.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, try to clarify with updated question title

Comment: You really should let Angular handle the validation for you. In my proposed answer, your `select` form control will be invalid, and you can show an error message for as long as it stays invalid. And remember, `null !== undefined`. `null` is a value, `undefined` is not.

Comment: I don’t see how that clarifies anything, it just states what we knew before already - the value has to be the empty string, for this to work as defined by the HTML5 spec. Why you insist on setting `undefined` as the value is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4):

i also had the same issue using following solved the problem for me

```
 <select class="o-field__input" [disabled]="isAnswerPresent" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" (change)="onAnswerChange()" required>
                <option [ngValue]="undefined">placeholder</option>

                <option [ngValue]="option" *ngFor="let option of optionSet;">option values</option>                     

            </select>
```

Comment: Using `undefined` as a `ngValue` for `option` is a correct approach to select default option when initializing `select` with an empty object. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To set a placeholder value of your select, set the state of the model to `null` and add an option with a `null` value. The required state will invalidate `null` as an option, which will set the form to invalid, and the specific control to be invalid. You can handle the validation message in any way you want.

**With reactive forms**

In your template

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <select [(ngModel)]="country" formControlName="country">
      <option [ngValue]="null">Choose a state</option>
      <option *ngFor="let option of items;"[ngValue]="option">{{option.name}}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

and in your component

```
form = new FormGroup({
country: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
```

**With template driven forms**

In your template

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <select name="countryTemplateForm" [ngModel]="countryTemplateForm" required>
    <option [ngValue]="null">Choose a country</option>
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
      {{ country.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

and in your component

```
countryTemplateForm = null;
countries = [
  { name: 'USA'},
  { name: 'India' },
  { name: 'France' }
];
```

[Have a look at this StackBlitz example!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-cq6iv6)

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, issue is "required alert" form submit, in your fiddle it does not exist form submit. [see](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-hbcwgo)

Comment: I've updated the Stackblitz to match your requirements!

Comment: with reactive forms works fine, but angular shows a warning:
"It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with  reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in a future version of Angular."

Comment: changing to <select formControlName="country"> ...... (without [(ngModel)]="country" and keeping [ngValue]) does not generate warnings (1 point)

Comment: Yes, that's expected when mixing reactive and template forms.

Answer (score 0):

Setting choose state value to empty string `<option value="">Choose a state</option>` ,
and in ts file declare `myDropDown` to empty string also,will solve problem.

```
 myDropDown = '';
```

or

```
 myDropDown= this.items[0].id;
```

html

```
 <form ngNativeValidate>
   <select [(ngModel)]="myDropDown"  (ngModelChange)="onChangeofOptions($event)" 
    required [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
     <option value="">Choose a state</option>
     <option *ngFor="let option of items;"[value]="option.id">{{option.name}}</option>
   </select>
   <input [hidden]="myDropDown !=='two'"type="text">
   <input type="submit" value="submit form">
  </form>
```

Comment: `<option value="">Choose a state</option>` won't select option default option, for that angular needs to set `<option [value]="undefined">Choose a state</option>`

Comment: If you want to use default option then select from list or explicitly set it in default option