# No person shown after selecting ALL genders from a dropdown

Tags: angular

The minimal code to produce the issue can be seen at [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mgsrmu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

**Objective**: Showing a list of persons based on the selected gender. If `All` is selected then all persons are shown.

**Issue**:

- When the page is first loaded, `All` is selected by default. All persons are shown. It works as expected.
- Selecting `male` shows a list of male persons. It works as expected.
- But if I reselect `All`, no person is shown. It is the unexpected result.

[image]

**Code Snippet**:

```html
<div>
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedFilter">
    <option [value]="undefined">All</option>
    <option *ngFor="let gender of ['male','female']" [value]="gender">
      {{gender}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let person of peopleByGender">
      {{person.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedFilter?: "male" | "female";

  people: { name: string; gender: "male" | "female"; }[] = [
    { name: "Anton", gender: "male" },
    { name: "Bob", gender: "male" },
    { name: "Cindy", gender: "female" }
  ];


  get peopleByGender(): readonly { name: string; gender: "male" | "female"; }[] {
    return this.people
      .filter(x => this.selectedFilter == undefined || x.gender == this.selectedFilter);
  }

}
```

#### Question

What causes this issue? And how to solve it?

Note: Using `type` or `interface` are intentionally ignored to focus on the main issue.

#### Logging

```
get peopleByGender(): readonly { name: string; gender: "male" | "female"; }[] 
{
  console.log(

  `Selected Filter: ${this.selectedFilter}. 
   Is it undefined? ${this.selectedFilter == undefined}`

  );

 // ... others
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you put a breakpoint or a log statement in `peopleByGender`, what value does `selectedFilter` have when you select `All`? Setting the value of an Option to `undefined` feels a little wonky. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/54571097/120955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<option>` values must be convertible to strings, because behind the scenes they're getting represented as HTML DOM.

[image: DOM Representation]

So when a user selects the "All" option, they're not changing the value to `undefined`: they're changing it to `"undefined"`.

If you omit the option's value entirely, the DOM will implicitly assign its inner text (`"All"`) to be its value.

Instead of trying to use `undefined`, use a special string value. For example, you could use "All", or you could just use an empty string:

```
  <option value="">All</option>
```

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedFilter: "male" | "female" | "" = "";

  people: { name: string; gender: "male" | "female"; }[] = [
    { name: "Anton", gender: "male" },
    { name: "Bob", gender: "male" },
    { name: "Cindy", gender: "female" }
  ];


  get peopleByGender(): readonly { name: string; gender: "male" | "female" | ""; }[] {
    return this.people
      .filter(x => this.selectedFilter === "" || x.gender == this.selectedFilter);
  }
```

Comment: I just knew that using `[ngValue]="undefined"` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should add value “all” to the All option and in your function check if the value of selected filter equals “all” and return this.people else run the filter method on your array and return that array.

Comment: I prefer `undefined`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [StriplingWarrior's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75264442/835073):

> So when a user selects the "All" option, they're not changing the value to `undefined`: they're changing it to `"undefined"`.

And because I want to keep using `undefined`, here is my trick.

```
get peopleByGender(): /* others ...*/ {

  if (this.selectedFilter?.toString() === String(undefined))
    this.selectedFilter = undefined;

  // others .....
}
```